# How to make my GridLayout to be in the center of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my Android layout. I wish to display a table with 3 rows on 3 columns. Each cell is a square (even) button. How do I get the center red square/button  to be in the center of my Android device? I must have this grid in the center of my screen and not at the top.

Square button code:

```
  public class SquareButton extends Button {
    public SquareButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public SquareButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }
    @Override public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        int size = width > height ? height : width;
        setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
    }
}
```

And my layout:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">


   <GridLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:rowCount="3"
       android:columnCount="3"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:foregroundGravity="center">

       <LinearLayout>

           <com.example.talangel.stacktests.SquareButton
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#FF0000"
               android:layout_weight="1"/>
           <com.example.talangel.stacktests.SquareButton
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#00FF00"
               android:layout_weight="1"/>
           <com.example.talangel.stacktests.SquareButton
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#0000FF"
               android:layout_weight="1"/>
       </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout>

           <com.example.talangel.stacktests.SquareButton
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#0000FF"
               android:layout_weight="1"/>
           <com.example.talangel.stacktests.SquareButton
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#FF0000"
               android:layout_weight="1"/>
           <com.example.talangel.stacktests.SquareButton
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#00FF00"
               android:layout_weight="1"/>
       </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout>

           <com.example.talangel.stacktests.SquareButton
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#00FF00"
               android:layout_weight="1"/>
           <com.example.talangel.stacktests.SquareButton
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#0000FF"
               android:layout_weight="1"/>
           <com.example.talangel.stacktests.SquareButton
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#FF0000"
               android:layout_weight="1"/>
       </LinearLayout>

   </GridLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try to change `android:layout_gravity="center"` to `android:gravity="center"` on parent view.

Comment: Yes, that worked!

Comment: i have posted it as answer.. Kindly mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: Yes mister, I will do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to change your code as..**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
```